# Windows Deployment Screen going blank and out of range

Tags: windows-7, wds, mdt

For some reason, all our Windows 7 deployment images seem to have developed a stange issue. As the install gets to the end of the process, the monitor is going blank and displaying 'out of range' messages. We have tried it on a couple of monitors and a couple of machines put same outcome.

I've dug into the logs in the \panther folder, and come accross a strange entry in \panther\unattendGC\setupact.log, it says -

```
2012-10-24 09:07:56, Info                         [msoobe.exe] Display mode is set to 1280x1024x32 [1Hz]
```

This seemed very odd (a refesh of 1Hz?), so i checked an older machine and it was set to 60hz as id expect.

Anyone know where this setting is comming from?

Cheers
Luke

Comment: Have you recently made any changes to.the out of box drivers?

Comment: some new ones might have been added, i did'nt think adding new ones would break anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the unatend.xml file on the task, found a display setting under OOBE and removed it. This seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It is possible when adding a new out of box driver for the new injected driver to have problems when used in a PE / WDS / MDT setup. I would suggest that you pull any new drivers, update your deployment share and republish your images. If that helps readd your drivers one by one.